# Evaluate an integral using contour integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, contour-integration

> Evaluate $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\cos(mx)}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,dx$$ given that  $m>0,a>b>0$.

I did the following integral and got my answer as 
$$\frac{\pi[\cos(bm i)-\cos(am i)]}{2(b^2-a^2)},$$ 
however the answer mention is 
$$\frac{\pi [ae^{-ma}-be^{-mb}]}{2(b^2-a^2)},$$ 
I have no idea how did the $cos$ vanish in the final-answer 
,can someone help me on this.

Comment: $\cos (it)=\frac  {e^{-t}-e^{t}} 2$. But your answer is different from the given answer. You will have to show us how you arrived at your answer,

Comment: please refer the link https://imgur.com/a/1jsN4mC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the complex integral

$\int_C \frac{z^2.e^{imz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}dz$

where $C$ being the closed contour oriented counterclockwise consisting of the real axis $(-\infty,\infty)$ together with a big semicircle $C_R: |z|=R$ in the upper half plane enclosing all the singularities.
Use Residue theorem to see

$2πi[Res(f,ai)+Res(f,bi)]=$$ \int_{C_R} \frac{z^2.e^{imz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}dz$$+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2.e^{imx}}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}dx$

and Jordan's lemma to show that the first integral goes to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have done the same please refer the link imgur.com/a/1jsN4mC I somehow get my final result in cos rather to the power of e

Comment: In the link you have given, the mistake was in choosing the correct integrand i.e. $\frac{z^2.e^{imz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}$ instead of $\frac{z^2cosmz}{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}$. And to trace out the required integral you have to compare the real parts of your final equation.

Comment: Moreover the first integral along the semicircular arc $C_R$ vanishes due to the fact that $|e^{imz}|=1$ in the evaluation of bound for the integrand. Note that $cos(mz)$ is unbounded so Jordan's lemma cannot be used in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply could you just explain me once on how did you convert cos(mz) to $e^{imz}$, because $z=e^{imz}$ so dx=$\frac{dz}{zim}$ did you change it from there,iam really thankful for your support

Comment: $e^{imz}=cos(mz)+isin(mz)$ so that with the function $e^{imz}$ in the numerator you just have to compare the real part in the end. Had there been $sin(mz)$ in the question then imaginary parts could be compared to get the final answer.